# Facebook February 2013 Breaking Changes - how to get rid of "fix now" message in App?

Tags: migration, facebook-apps

48 mins ago I received an alert that says :

February 2013 Breaking Changes
fix now  48 minutes ago
Your app, needs to be updated for the February 2013 Breaking Changes.
Once your app is compliant, set the migration setting to "Enabled" in the Advanced section of the App Dashboard.

Your app needs to be updated by Tuesday 5th February 2013

I got this today on Monday 11th February.  I found some instructions saying go to your migration settings and check the box for February breaking changes but I don't have a box for that as obviously the deadline has passed.  I have a box for March and April changes and I checked those so in my alerts page they are showing as resolved but the February one still says "fix now".

My app is only used by me to create an "About" page for my facebook page tabs and is set up using Wordpress plugin called Facebook Tab Manager.  All it does is display text that I type into the WP plugin and it displays that as an about page in FB tabs.  It is still working as far as I can tell - I can see it.  People who visit my page can click on the tab and read the text.  That's all it does.

But how can I get rid of this "fix now" alert for February or make it go away?  Is it still there because there is still something I need to change in the app settings because I can't see what it would be.

I wanted to contact Facebook to say why send me an alert 6 days after the deadline has passed but there seems to be no way to do that either.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic here. Not closevoting but I want to see the community opinion whether it is.

Comment: hi, I don't understand what you mean, but I'm trying to find help and was directed here from facebook.  This is my first post, if it's in the wrong place can it be moved to the right section?